# Sort multiple `by` columns with equation in key

Tags: pandas

Would like to sort a df with an equation in the key as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 
                   'price': [1, 2, np.nan], 
                   'cost': [3, np.nan, 1]})
```

`df.sort_values(by=['price', 'cost'], key=lambda x: x.price/x.cost)`
...doesn't work and gives the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'price'`

What's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better compute the ratio, sort this and reindex:

```
out = df.loc[df['price'].div(df['cost']).sort_values().index]
```

Or, if you have tricky indices, with [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
out = df.iloc[np.argsort(df['price'].div(df['cost']))]
```

Output:

```
  name  price  cost
0    x    1.0   3.0
1    y    2.0   NaN
2    z    NaN   1.0
```